# How to use a switch construct with variable-length strings in Embedded Matlab?

Tags: string, matlab, switch-statement, matlab-coder

I never liked Embedded MATLAB much, precisely because of situations like what I'm about to ask :) In my experience, conversion to Embedded MATLAB often takes a lot more effort than simply re-writing the thing in C (when you know C and the MATLAB API well enough).

But oh well, I guess some things just can't be avoided.

Anyway, here's my problem. In Embedded MATLAB, as it is in R2010a, you can't do this:

```
for ii = <some range>

    parameter = <some string> 

    switch parameter

        case 'first_string'
            % do stuff

        case 'another_string_that''s_larger_than_first_string'
            % do other stuff
    end

    % ...continue here

end
```

where `<some string>` changes every iteration. This is because the length of the string `parameter` is variable, meaning that this definition of `parameter` is beyond Embedded Matlab's capabilities:

> ??? Non-constant expression or empty matrix. This expression must be
>   constant because its value determines the size or class of some
>   expression. The limitation to constant strings applies only for
>   switches on strings, not switches on numbers.

Changing the `switch` to its more direct form

```
switch <some string> 
    ...
end
```

doesn't help of course:

```
??? Expected a numeric value. Found a mxArray
```

Even constraining the size of the string to a known constant length does not help:

```
parameter = char_array(ii, 1:4);  % <--- NOTE: length is 4 characters

switch parameter
    ...
end
```

but no luck:

> ??? Non-constant expression or empty matrix. This expression must be
>   constant because its value determines the size or class of some
>   expression. The limitation to constant strings applies only for
>   switches on strings, not switches on numbers.

I see two ways out:

1. Map all permissible strings to some numeric representation, and use a switch on the numbers
2. Use `strcmp(i)` inside a huge `if-elseif-elseif-...-else-end` construct.

Both are equally ugly IMHO, with 2. perhaps being uglier (you'd need another extrinsic function, `strcmp`)...

So, is there any *elegant* way out of this?

Comment: I guess padding the string with space to equal length would work? (It isn't the elegant solution you were looking for though.)

Comment: @user1884905: no, I tried that...in fact, in my real function the first 4 characters uniquely determine the strings, so I tried just using the first 4 characters; no luck, same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't know of any other method except the alternatives you mention.

To make things worse, MATLAB has no built-in char array to double scalar hash function. Hence, if you want to map strings to numbers then you need to provide a custom hash function.

Personally, I'd go with your second method. It's ugly but readable.

Since you say that you only need to consider the first 4 chars of each string, another option to map your strings to numbers is by explicit lookup:

```
function y = fcn(u)
%#codegen

    y = u;

    cases = [
        '1111'
        '2222'
        '3333'
    ];

    for i = 1 : 3
        switch i
            case 1                
                p = '1111a';
            case 2
                p = '2222bb';
            otherwise
                p = '3333ccc';
        end      

        for j = 1 : size(cases, 1)
            if isequal(cases(j, 1 : 4), p)
                switch j
                    case 1
                        y = y + 1;
                    case 2
                        y = y + 2;
                    case 3
                        y = y + 3;
                end
            end
        end        
    end
end
```

In my opinion this is not really readable and probably wastes a lot of time if you have a large number of strings. You may come up with something more performant, but I'd still consider this a hack.

Comment: Thanks, it's what I was afraid of. I solved it with the fugly `if-elseif-...-else-end` construct, which I thought was indeed the most readable alternative. Mapping strings to some arbitrary number felt a bit like forcing a Volkswagen Beetle into low Earth orbit...just slightly beyond its design constraints :)